# Matching domain structure on staging server on LAN?

Tags: centos7, httpd.conf, dns-hosting

When we develop websites on the staging server (CentOS) on the LAN, we end up storing it in something like:

```
/var/www/html/project1.com
```

And to access it through a web browser on the LAN:

```
http://ourserver/project1.com
```

When it gets published on a public hosting service it is then:

```
http://project1.com
```

Is there a way to match the same domain structure on the staging server for the LAN as when it is published? So that during development when we type in http://project1.com in a web browser, it knows to go to http://ourserver/project1.com?

I've not been able to find documentation that describes doing this. What I've seen so far is geared towards domains that are publicly being hosted with a public registered DNS.

I have looked into /etc/hosts, but that doesn't allow something like this:

```
ourserver/project1.com project1.com
```

which what I would want to map project1.com requests on the LAN to point to http://ourserver/project1.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't resolve a URL such as `ourserver/project1.com` with DNS or hosts, just the left hand side separated by the forward slash. All you can really do is configure a virtual host on your staging server to point at your project folder and use hosts or a local DNS server to resolve the domain.

Comment: `can’t do... with DNS...`, followed by `...or use a local DNS server...`. Well, which is it?

Comment: You can't resolve `ourserver/project1.com` using DNS or hosts, only the left hand side of the URL, as separated by the forward slash.

Comment: I know that, but your answer could be revised to clarify what you mean. Right now it’s ambiguous.

Comment: Updated the answer.